# Printing PDF-files via network extremely slow

Tags: printing, networking, pdf, evince, okular

I encounter grave problems trying to print PDF-files, no matter whether I use Evince, Okular or any other linux program. The Documents are printed extremely slowly or even completely fail to print at all. I have tried printing from various Ubuntu-Installations on different network-printers (canon and lexmark), with the same result. On the other hand the same files are printed swiftly through Windows, which is a pity, since I do not want to use Windows.

Are there any solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it just network printing?  Can you print to a locally printer via `xpdf` - i.e. using LPR not CUPS.  Possibly this old bug is still occurring - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poppler/+bug/382379

Comment: Printing pdf-files locally works but not at the speed it does under Windows. Is there a way to fix the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions to try:

- use xpdf: i.e. `xpdf <document name>` should automatically direct to your default printer
- if its a laser printer try adding a printer with using "Generic" as the manufacturer, and "Generic PCL5e printer" as the model i.e. most lasers support PCL.
- When printing - print to a file - give it a name and print to a .ps file.  Then open up the .ps file.  It should reopen in evince.  This time print it again to your printer.

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1073942.html)

Comment: Great, the "Generic PCL5e" driver works for me. Thank you so much! Cheers

Comment: Don't try this with a **Brother** network laser printer.

Answer (score 3):

Just for people to who it would also happen: I had the same problem, and in my case the solution was also to change the driver: more precisely **change** my footmatic/**pxl** color driver **to** the footmatic/**postscript** equivalent.

My printer was a Sharp MX-2300N, and the "Generic PCL5e printer" only enabled to print in grey scale, so I really had to stay on the manufacturer drivers.

Well, actually I have no idea why it worked, I just did it because an other printer on the network had also a postscript driver and was working perfectly well...

What's actually the difference between postscript and pxl drivers?

Comment: Funnily enough, this page: [link](http://www.iheartubuntu.com/2011/04/ubuntu-pdf-printing-is-slow.html) is proposing exactly the opposite solution to what worked with me...